# Determine $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$ if we know that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = 0.3$, $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}) = 0.6$, where $A$ and $B$ are independent

Tags: probability

I have the following question:

Given that events A and B are independent with $P(A \cap B)=0.3$ and $P(A \cap B')=0.6$, find $P(A \cup B)$.

Considering $P(A \cap B')=0.6$, then $P(A) - P(A \cap B) = 0.6$. Thus $P(A) = 0.6 + 0.3 = 0.9$. Then, as $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, then $P(B) = 0.3/0.9 = 1/3$.
I know that the union of two events is equal to $P(A) + P(B)- P(A \cap B)$.
Then the union is equal to $0.9 + 0.33 - 0.3 = 0.93$.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: It is corrcet only to two decimal spaces. $\frac 1  3 $ is not equal to $0.33$ Also you keep saying union of events for probability of union of events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, so it is $A$ and $B^{c}$.

Having said that, we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) = 0.3\\\\
\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B^{c}) = 0.6
\end{cases} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(A) = 0.9\\\\
\mathbb{P}(B) = 1/3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consequently, we deduce that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cup B) & = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\\\\
& = 0.9 + 1/3 - 0.3\\\\
& = 14/15
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
ab & = & 0.3\\
a(1-b) & = & 0.6
\end{eqnarray*}
Solve this for $a$ and $b$.

Then use $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$.